# android - ListView и SimpleAdapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Уже почти год мне никак не поддаётся `ListView`. Для меня это очень сложный виджет, постоянные проблемы и нервы с багами во время прокрутки. Много статей как на русском, так и английском перечитаны. Народ, обьясните хоть вы, раз и навсегда, как правильно организовать адаптер? Делаю чат, все шло ровно, как только дело дошло до тестирования, появились нехорошие отзывы, при прокрутке сообщения живут своей жизнью - нет бы встать на месте, они меняются данными, например ником отправителя, текстом сообщения, временем отправки. Дайте мне МАКСИМАЛЬНУЮ критику, уже не могу так жить. Код...

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> adapterList;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    int type;

    public CustomAdapter(List<? extends Map<String, String>> dat)
    {
        adapterList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) dat;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return adapterList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return adapterList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (adapterList.get(position).get("author").equals(nick)) 
             type = 0;
        else type = 1;
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, final ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if(v==null){
        v = mInflater.inflate((getItemViewType(position)==0) ? R.layout.item_right : R.layout.item_left, null);


        HashMap<String,String> fast_parse = adapterList.get(position);
        String author_str = fast_parse.get("author");
        String client_str = fast_parse.get("client");
        String text_str = fast_parse.get("text");
        String data_str = fast_parse.get("data");
        TextView tv_full_author = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.full_nick);
        TextView tv_circle_author = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.first_char_nick);
        TextView tv_client = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.reply_marker);
        TextView tv_text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message);
        TextView tv_data = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        tv_full_author.setText(author_str);
        tv_circle_author.setText(author_str.substring(0,1));
        if(!client_str.equals("0"))
        {
            tv_client.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_client.setText(client_str+",");

            if(client_str.equals(nick)&&(getItemViewType(position)==1))
            {
                tv_client.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A40dff"));
            }
        }
        tv_text.setText(text_str);
        tv_data.setText(data_str);
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

**UPD**

От сервера мне приходит `JSON` с сообщениями, я его парсю и в `HashMap` отправляю в адаптер. Разметки две - правая для своих сообщений, левая для чужих. В случае если отправителем сообщения являешься ты используется правая разметка, иначе левая. Если обращение к тебе, оно выделяется цветом

**UPD - CODE 1**

Добавил каждому `if`-у свой `else`, но **не помогло**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> adapterList;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    int type;

    public CustomAdapter(List<? extends Map<String, String>> dat)
    {
        adapterList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) dat;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return adapterList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return adapterList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (adapterList.get(position).get("author").equals(nick)) 
             type = 0;
        else type = 1;
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, final ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if(v==null){
        v = mInflater.inflate((getItemViewType(position)==0) ? R.layout.item_right : R.layout.item_left, null);


        HashMap<String,String> fast_parse = adapterList.get(position);
        String author_str = fast_parse.get("author");
        String client_str = fast_parse.get("client");
        String text_str = fast_parse.get("text");
        String data_str = fast_parse.get("data");
        TextView tv_full_author = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.full_nick);
        TextView tv_circle_author = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.first_char_nick);
        TextView tv_client = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.reply_marker);
        TextView tv_text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message);
        TextView tv_data = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        tv_full_author.setText(author_str);
        tv_circle_author.setText(author_str.substring(0,1));
        if(!client_str.equals("0")){
            tv_client.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_client.setText(client_str+",");

            if(client_str.equals(nick)&&(getItemViewType(position)==1))
tv_client.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A40dff"));
else tv_client.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        else{
            tv_client.setText("");
            tv_client.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        tv_text.setText(text_str);
        tv_data.setText(data_str);
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

**UPD - CODE 2**

Работает! А я пошел учить холдер.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> adapterList;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    int type;

    public CustomAdapter(List<? extends Map<String, String>> dat)
    {
        adapterList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) dat;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return adapterList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return adapterList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (adapterList.get(position).get("author").equals(nick)) 
             type = 0;
        else type = 1;
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, final ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if(v==null)
        v = mInflater.inflate((getItemViewType(position)==0) ? R.layout.item_right : R.layout.item_left, null);


        HashMap<String,String> fast_parse = adapterList.get(position);
        String author_str = fast_parse.get("author");
        String client_str = fast_parse.get("client");
        String text_str = fast_parse.get("text");
        String data_str = fast_parse.get("data");
        TextView tv_full_author = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.full_nick);
        TextView tv_circle_author = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.first_char_nick);
        TextView tv_client = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.reply_marker);
        TextView tv_text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message);
        TextView tv_data = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        tv_full_author.setText(author_str);
        tv_circle_author.setText(author_str.substring(0,1));
        if(!client_str.equals("0"))
        {
            tv_client.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_client.setText(client_str+",");

            if(client_str.equals(nick)&&(getItemViewType(position)==1))
            {
                tv_client.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#A40dff"));
            }
            else{
                tv_client.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        }
        else{
            tv_client.setText("");
            tv_client.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        tv_text.setText(text_str);
        tv_data.setText(data_str);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) много статей перечитали, то где `ViewHolder`, о нем же в каждой статье о адаптерах к `ListView` упоминают. 2) не забывайте о том что элементы переиспользуются, т.е. к вам в `getView` прилетит элемент уже вышедший за границы экрана - если кратко, то на любой `if` должен быть `else`

Comment: то есть если в `if`'e есть `tv_client.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`, то в `else`'e должно быть `tv_client.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` так же и для ифа с цветом, добавить цвет по дефолту

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46523/discussion-on-question-by---android-listview--simpleadapter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том что, что данное условие сформировано не верно:

```
    if(v==null){
        ...
    }
    return v;
```

Получается что если `v` не равно `null`(что будет происходить при прокрутке `ListView` в связи с переиспользованием `item`'ов), то оно не будет заполнятся информацией соответствующей позиции элемента.

Следовательно заполнение `v` информацией необходимо вынести из условия.